# Tabla compartida en base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, relaciones, modelorelacional

Soy nueva por acá. Tengo dos tablas que entre si no están relacionadas, pero ambas necesitan de una tercera. Me explico con un ejemplo...

```
TablaUsuarios (idUsuario, nombre, apellido)
TablaEmpresas (idempresa, nombre_e, rif)
```

Para ambas tablas necesito registrar correos; un usuario puede tener varios correos (**1:M**), y también una empresa(**1:M**), así que por normalización separé esta información en una tabla   llamada **Email** que estructuré de la siguiente manera

```
TablaEmail(idcorreo, direccion, propietario, idpropietario)
```

Con las columnas *propietario e idpropietario* como clave única, donde se suponía que quedaría el registro de la siguiente manera:

```
TablaUsuarios                                TablaEmpresas
idusuario | nombre | apellido                idempresa | nombre_e   | rif
    1     |  María | sosa                        1     | Empresa1   |123


TablaEmail
idemail | direccion       | propietario   |idpropietario
   1    | maria@gmail.com | TablaUsuarios |   1        
   2    | emp1@gmail.com  | TablaEmpresas |   1
```

Pero al hacer un registro de alguna de las tablas me obliga a hacer un registro en ambas (Usuarios-Empresas) lo cual no debería ser una norma, ya que entre ellas no poseen ninguna relación.

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme se los agradecería. Saludos..

Comment: Para poder contestar esta clase de preguntas se necesitan saber las reglas de negocios. Decir que una tabla esta aparte porque la necesitas para otras tablas no es suficiente. Cual seria la logica detras de ponerla aparte?

Comment: Hola, debes tener en cuenta que si ambos foreign key (de usuario y empresa) que se relacionan con las dos tablas están como not null  ambos sera necesario que hayas ingresado usuario y empresa para registrar un correo, mi sugerencia es que ambos acepten valores nulosy así solo ingreses el foreign key necesario.

Comment: Si claro, ambos tienen razón, les agradezco, olvidé comentar en mi pregunta que está en una tabla aparte porque tanto las empresas como los usuarios podrían tener mas de un correo. Es por este motivo que se encuentra en una tabla aparte, por su relación N:1

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo vas a relacionar los datos de la tabla de correos con diversas tablas con lo que debería ser asi:

- **Tablacorreo** las columnas (**idcorreo**, direccion, idpropietario)
- **TablaUsuarios** (idUsuario, nombre, apellido, **idcorreo**)
- **TablaEmpresa** (idpropietario, nombre_empresa, rif, **idcorreo**)

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Si fuera de esta forma, no seria necesario otra tabla, ya que la relacion es 1 a 1 y la tabla correo no aporta nada, salvo que una persona comparta correo con una empresa... raro...

Answer (score 1):

La relación no es difícil. Tanto en la tabla de `Empresa` como en la de `Usuario` debes tener un campo `correoId`.

Este campo `correoId`, es una `foreign key` a la tabla de `Correos`.

Entonces en la tabla de `Correos` por ejemplo pueden existir los registros:

```
id  - correo
1   - pepe@example.com
2   - exitos@example.com
3   - jose@example.com
```

Y luego en la tabla de `Usuarios`

Pepe con `idCorreo` 1 y José con `idCorreo` 3

Y en la tabla de `Empresas`

Existos SA con `idCorreo` 2

Podría darse el caso incluso que Manuel, el dueño de la empresa Exitos use el mismo correo que el de la empresa con lo que en `Usuarios` tendríamos, adicionalmente:

Manuel con `idCorreo` 2 (Mismo `idCorreo` que Existos SA en la tabla de `Empresas`)

La `foreing key`, además enforza `integridad referencial`, es decir que los ids cargados en las tablas de `Empresas` y `Usuarios`, deben existir en la tabla de `Correos`.